What is the purpose of this R-C snubber in the synchronizing cabinet?
I have an R-C snubber in the sync cabinet, which is causing me problems. When the Switch is set to a sync position on any offline generator the voltage on A phase of the generator PT's drops 3 VAC from 600 to 597, 15 VAC on the B phase from 600 to 585 VAC and increases 12 VAC on the C phase from 600 to 612 VAC. I can live with this as this does not affect the synchronization, but if the switch is not put back to OFF position after synchronization or it is put to any position where a generator is already load sharing online it affects the voltages, and the load-sharing equipment drives the reactive power to the opposite site (because of the voltage change). I just don't see a purpose for this R-C circuit in the system. Can anyone explain the reason it was installed in the first place? I have an automatic synchronizer and load-sharing control and when the synchronization is done automatically the switch is not involved and everything functions as designed. The problem exists only when the sync switch is turned ON.


